# Trying to pull a value from a column that is not the PK

Tags: ms-access

**EDITED WITH UPDATED CODE**

I am pulling from 2 tables from my scheduling software's DB.

```
dbo_Employee
  empid(PK) / empName / empAddr / empCityLid / empStateLid
      1     /  Name   / Address /     519    /    323
      2     /  Name   / Address /     520    /    323

dbo_ListValues
  lstid(PK) / lstEntid / lstTypeid / lstValue   / lstText2
    323     /     1    /     13    /    OH      /  OHIO
    519     /     1    /     17    / Lancaster  /   323
    520     /     1    /     17    / SugarGrove /   323
```

I want to be able to pull OH, Lancaster & Sugar Grove when I query my employees.

I am back to the basics at this point because everything I have tried has failed me so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo_Employee.empId, 
                dbo_Employee.empName, 
                dbo_Employee.empAddr1, 
                dbo_Employee.empAddr2, 
                dbo_Employee.empCityLid, 
                dbo_Employee.empStateLid, 
                dbo_Employee.empZip, 
                dbo_Employee.empHphone, 
                dbo_Employee.empMphone, 
                dbo_Employee.empDateStarted, 
                dbo_Employee.empDateLeft
FROM dbo_Employee, dbo_ListValues;
```

The working code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.empId as ID, 
                E.empName as NAME, 
                E.empAddr1 as ADDRESS, 
                E.empAddr2 as ADDRESS2, 
                Cities.lstValue as CITY,
                States.lstValue as STATE,
                E.empZip as ZIP, 
                E.empHphone as H_PHONE, 
                E.empMphone as M_PHONE, 
                E.empDateStarted as STARTED, 
                E.empDateLeft as DATE_LEFT

FROM (dbo_Employee as E
         INNER JOIN dbo_ListValues as Cities 
         on E.empCityLid = Cities.lstId
         )
         INNER JOIN dbo_ListValues as States
         on E.empStateLid = States.lstId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.empId, 
            E.empName, 
            E.empAddr1, 
            E.empAddr2, 
            E.empCityLid, 
            E.empStateLid, 
            E.empZip, 
            E.empHphone, 
            E.empMphone, 
            E.empDateStarted, 
            E.empDateLeft,
          Cities.lstValue as City,
          States.lstValue as State
FROM (dbo_Employee as E
     inner join dbo_ListValues as Cities
      on E.empCityLid  = Cities.lstid
  )
inner join dbo_ListValues as States
   on E.empStateLid  = States.lstid
```

This assumes that the Lookup fields are not-null. If they are nullable, use left joins so that you don't lose data from your return set.